# Laravel Controller SQL: joining two tables multiplies the output

Tags: sql, ajax, laravel, join, duplicates

To quickly summarize, my first table's rows gets multiplied by the amount of rows in the second table possibly due to my join:

**Table 1:**(bbr_group) I only have two rows

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnHBP.png)

**Table 2:**(bbr_group_type) I only need to get `group_type_name`, joined by `group_type_id`

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wu0Zr.png)

**Controller:**

```
public function fetchgroup(){
    $all_groups = HmsBbrGroup::join('hms_bbr_group_type', 'hms_bbr_group.group_type_id', '=', 'hms_bbr_group.group_type_id')
                               ->orderBy('group_id', 'ASC')->get();
    return response()->json([
        'all_groups'=>$all_groups,
    ]);
}
```

**Table:** (with ajax)

```
                success: function (response){
                    var tbody="";
                    $.each(response.all_groups, function (key, group) {
                    tbody+=`
                        <tr>
                            <td><p class="font-weight-bold mb-0">${group.group_name}</p>${group.group_description}</td>
                            <td><p>${group.group_type_name}</p></td>
                            <td><p>users here</p></td>
                            <td><p>status here</p></td>
                            <td>
                                <button type="button" value="${group.group_id}" class="edit_group btn btn-outline-secondary"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i> Edit</button>
                                <button type="button" value="${group.group_id}" class="delete_group btn btn-outline-secondary"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i> Delete</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>`;
                    });
                    
                    $('#main-group-list tbody').html(tbody)
                }
```

Here is the situation of my output: As you can see even if there are only two rows, it shows the row with every group name from the second table

[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnAyG.png)

I need to show the table with only the two rows in `hms_bbr_group` with the left join `group_type_name`. In this case, both are "General"

I am not sure if the join in the controller or the table is the reason for the duplicates. I'd like some feed back if this line is correct:

```
$all_groups = HmsBbrGroup::join('hms_bbr_group_type', 'hms_bbr_group.group_type_id', '=', 'hms_bbr_group.group_type_id')
```

Any help would be great. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your joining condition is wrong. You are using `hms_bbr_group` table in both side of equal. I think this would be like following:

```
$all_groups = HmsBbrGroup::join('hms_bbr_group_type', 'hms_bbr_group.group_type_id', '=', 'hms_bbr_group_type.group_type_id')
                          ->orderBy('group_id', 'ASC')->get();
```

Comment: its my bad, i just overlooked this. everything seems to be fine now thank you